# pandas replace dataframe cell values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where some cells have a string like "<0.5".

I would like to iterate over the entire dataframe, and for any cells that contain the less than sign, I would like to replace the entire cell with 0.0.

So for example, <0.4 becomes 0.0

Edit to add some code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(infl)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        if "<" in df.ix[i,j]:
            df.ix[i,j] = 0.0
```

This produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\00Working\81_WinPython_32bit_2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 538, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "Z:/working/MINING/2015/01_read_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    if "<" in df.ix[i,j]:
TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable
```

This code also does not work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(infl)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        if '<' in df.iloc[i][j]:
            df[i,j] = 0.0
```

This code gives the same error as above.

Comment: `if '<' in your_dataframe.iloc[your][index]: your_dataframe[your][index] = 0.0`. Guessing here, please post your code.

Comment: @brock added some code. Tried your suggestion, but it gives an error.

Comment: Ah I see what is wrong: you cannot iterate `df.shape`. It returns simply the size aka 'shape' of the item. Instead use `df.iterrows()` or `df.iteritems()`.

Comment: @brock I'm a little confused as I can certainly access the values in the dataframe by iterating over it. For example: `for i in range(df.shape[0]): for j in range(df.shape[1]): print df.iloc[i][j]` this code works fine. Therefore, I can iterate over every value in the dataframe fine. Could you please provide an answer using `df.iterrows()` or `df.iteritems()`? I'm a pandas newb and not sure how to make that work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`applymap()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function to do particular item in all cells,

```
In [92]: df
Out[92]: 
     a    b
0    1  <.3
1    2    2
2  <.3  <.4
3    4    5

In [93]: df.applymap(lambda x: 0 if "<" in str(x) else x)
Out[93]: 

   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  2
2  0  0
3  4  5
```

converting cell `lambda x` to string since int/float will fail for `in`.

Comment: `df.apply` works as well and is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could find that values with `str.contains` and then fill them with what you want (with example from @WoodChopper):

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
     a    b
0    1  <.3
1    2    2
2  <.3  <.4
3    4    5

In [13]: df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('<'))] = 0

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  2
2  0  0
3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way. Take a look at [DataFrame.replace()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

This is untested, but you should be able to do what you want with:

`df.replace(to_replace='.*<.*', value=0.0, regex=True)`